# Running cmd commands

Tags: c#, cmd

I run a cmd command in c# and somehow it usually crashes. I mean, when I work with smaller files (I run some kind of converter software) it almost always suceeds, but when I try it with larger ones it just crashes. I want to know where. And therefore I would like to run the command and see all the details, like the progress. 
When I run it normally, by hand in command line, it writes like : Welcome to ... Progress : ... and so on. But how could I see that in C#? I only see the blank black stuff.

Here's my code. I tried to write out the StandardOutput, the StandardError, but it seems like its good. So my only chance is to see the details of the stuff running.

```
process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir.Parent.FullName;
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"make html");
k = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");
k.ReadToEnd();
```

Thank you guys, I hope you can help. Have a nice day!

EDIT: Now I see the output, by writing make html > output.txt
So my problem now is, why can I run exactly the same command from cmd, by hand, and why I cannot from C#
Thanks

Comment: Does the program your running write to stdout?

Comment: You can just run `make html` instead of spawning `cmd` and pretending to use it interactively ...

Comment: you can also add `> text.txt` and see the output

Comment: it does run like always. for smaller files it takes like 20 seconds to complete that command, but for like the double lenght of the file, i waited 20 minutes and it still says: make html. So it does not end for some reason

Comment: mm, i added > text.txt and it writes me the output. and now i see where it stops for some reason. but i have no clue why, it always works. Thank you very much AnnArbor87, and everyone else!

Comment: it does not work if i immidiately try to run make html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track for the redirection, you just have to hook up what you want to do with it...

[Please check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832320/redirecting-console-output-to-a-log-file/21833739#21833739) but here is a portion...

```
startinfo.OutputDataReceived += DOSOutputResultsHandler;

StringBuilder DOSOutputResults = new StringBuilder();


protected void DOSOutputResultsHandler(object sendingProcess,
   System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
      // track data into the NORMAL output string builder
      DOSOutputResults.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you DRapp, now i see where it stops. But I still have no clue why. It DOES run when I write the exact same commands. How could that be? Maybe some kind of permission reasons? Like I cannot run it as administrator or something like that? (I don't know, I do not run cmd as admin either.

Comment: @aakos, so now you have the results which is good.  You might be able to get the results of the string builder error through the debugger, copy out to a text file (or copy to clipboard via watch window and looking at it with text visualizer).  Maybe we can help look at it and might throw other options for you.

Answer (score 0):

So now I have an answer, that worked for me.

I tried many ways to write out the output, and see where it crashes.

After a few turns I realized it starts working when I write out the output into a txt, with the following two methods:

I used the cmd: "make html > infooutput.txt" and "make html 2> infoerrors.txt".

I cannot explain why this works, but as I put these lines everywhere, where I called this command, it starts working. 
Thank you very much for your help, you may find other great advices in the comment sections, for me they did not work properly.